# How can I tell which characters can equip which custom parts?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Different characters, including Miis, can equip different custom parts. For example, Mario can wear overalls, but Yoshi cannot. I've been getting new parts, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to view which characters can use any given part. Currently I have to begin creating a custom version of each character and check to see which parts I can equip, which is very inconvenient with so many characters and so many parts.

[image: custom parts]

Is there a way to view which custom part types a character can equip, or which characters can equip a specific part?

If not, is there a chart available online?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Unmarked secret character spoilers ahead.**

There is no easy way, aside from "intuitive knowledge of the character's aesthetics", to know what kind of equipment they can equip.

There is, however, a chart available on [this page](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Equipment). It's kinda large, but here it is in text form:

- Every character can equip Brawn/Protection/Agility Badges.
- Mario: Gloves, Overalls, Shoes
- Luigi: Gloves, Overalls, Shoes
- Dr. Mario: Gloves, Tie, Shoes
- Peach: Toad, Dress, Pumps
- Rosalina: Staff, Dress, Pumps
- Bowser: Fake Nails, Shell, Dash Mushroom
- Bowser Jr.: Drill, Shell, Dash Mushroom
- Yoshi: Egg, Saddle, Boots
- Wario: Gloves, Overalls, Shoes
- Donkey Kong: Banana, Tie, Dash Mushroom
- Diddy Kong: Banana, Hat, Rocketbarrel Pack
- Link: Sword, Shield, Boots
- Toon Link: Sword, Shield, Boots
- Zelda: Magic Stone, Dress, Boots
- Sheik: Needles, Suit, Shoes
- Ganondorf: Magic Stone, Cape, Shin Guards
- Samus: Arm Cannon, Suit, Booster
- Zero Suit Samus: Beam Whip, Suit, Booster
- Kirby: Lollipop, Hat, Turbo Boost
- Meta Knight: Sword, Mask, Turbo Boost
- King Dedede: Hammer, Coat, Turbo Boost
- Fox: Blaster, Jacket, Shin Guards
- Falco: Blaster, Jacket, Shin Guards
- All Pokémon: X Attack, X Defense, X Speed
- Captain Falcon: Gloves, Suit, Boots
- Ness: Bat, Hat, Shoes
- Lucas: Bat, Clothes, Shoes
- Marth: Sword, Cape, Boots
- Lucina: Sword, Cape, Boots
- Roy: Sword, Cape, Boots
- Ike: Sword, Cape, Boots
- Robin: Tome, Coat, Boots
- Mr. Game & Watch: Torch, Watch Battery, Microchip
- Pit: Sacred Treasure, Raiment, Sandals
- Dark Pit: Sacred Treasure, Raiment, Sandals
- Palutena: Staff, Shield, Sandals
- Olimar: Pikmin, Space Suit, Boots
- R.O.B.: Zapper, Block, Booster
- Little Mac: Boxing Gloves, Clothes, Boots
- Duck Hunt: Zapper, Collar, Feather
- Villager: Lloid, Clothes, Shoes
- Wii Fit Trainer: Protein, CLothes, Shoes
- Shulk: Sword, Jacket, Shoes
- Sonic: Gloves, Ring, Shoes
- Mega Man: Arm Cannon, Helmet, Booster
- Pac-Man: Gloves, Helmet, Boots
- Ryu: Gloves, Clothes, Shin Guards
- Mii Brawler: Gloves, Jacket, Boots
- Mii Swordfighter: Sword, Jacket, Boots
- Mii Gunner: Arm Cannon, Jacket, Boots

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. You missed the pokemon in your list, but I see that they all use "X" things from the link you provided.

Comment: Actually I have them listed under "All Pokémon" for brevity.

Comment: Oh, that explains why a search for their individual names didn't find anything. I accepted your answer. I wish they had thought to include this info in the game.

Comment: It looks like Charizard can also use Fake Nails.